# NASM equivalent for MASM code

Tags: assembly, nasm, masm

I'm trying to write a code to read a user input string in assembly language but i'm forced to use NASM. The code below is designed for MASM and I want to 'translate' to NASM but I'm having problem with 'buffer' instructions. Why can't i declare something like buffer[bx+2]? What is the correct 'translation' ?

```
org 100h

mov ah, 09h                     ; print function
mov dx, offset nameprompt      
int 21h

mov ah, 0ah                     ; buffered string input
mov dx, offset buffer
int 21h

mov ah, 09h
mov dx, offset crlf
int 21h

mov dx, offset yourname
int 21h

xor bx, bx
mov bl, buffer[1]
mov buffer[bx+2], '$'
mov dx, offset buffer + 2
int 21h

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h

buffer db 255,0,255 dup(0)
nameprompt db "Enter your name: $"
yourname db "Your name is: $"
crlf db 13,10,"$"
```

Comment: `buffer[bx+2]` would be `[buffer+bx+2]` in NASM

Comment: I had an issue with mov [buffer+bx+2], '$' but i solved by adding mov al, '$' and then mov [buffer+bx+2], al. First of all i cleared ax. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried out this code with NASM. Here's what I found:

- eliminate "offset", e.g.: `mov dx, offset nameprompt` -> `mov dx, nameprompt`
- as Brendan commented, lines like `buffer[bx+2]` -> `[buffer+bx+2]`
- `offset buffer + 2` -> `buffer + 2`
- this line appears invalid: `buffer db 255,0,255 dup(0)`; according to the NASM manual, dup isn't available-- look for the TIMES directive ([see this section of the manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html))